# redux-persist persisting my logged in state

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I am currently trying to use redux-persist to persist state after page refreshes. The problem is that, since my application uses OAuth flow for authentication, going to the 3rd party server for authentication persists my logged in state because leaving my website counts as a refresh.

For example, I go to my website and I am not currently logged in. So, even though I successfully log in via the 3rd party serve, when I get redirected, I am still "logged out" because I was logged out because going to the 3rd party server. Vice versa, if I am logged in and try to log out, I am still going to be logged in even though I successfully logged out.

Does anyone have any ideas how to get around this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Redux Persist comes with `whitelisting` and `blacklisting` of the reducers. So you need to `blacklist` your `auth` reducer, or make a [`nested persist`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#nested-persists) depending upon your use case. As mentioned in the example docs [here](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#blacklist--whitelist)

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  blacklist: ['auth'] // your reducer name
};
```